# How can I set up scheduled queries in BigQuery with timezone support (through Python SDK)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In the BigQuery UI, I can schedule a query with a specific timezone (as you can see in the screenshot below).

[image]
[image]

With these settings, I'm able to schedule my query at the correct local time, but when I try to automate this process with Python I can't see any option to specify the timezone (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)

```
def create_scheduled_query(project_id, dataset_id, query_string, dest_table, write_disposition=WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE):
    parent = client.project_path(project_id)

    transfer_config = google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict(
        {
            "destination_dataset_id": dataset_id,
            "display_name": dest_table,
            "data_source_id": "scheduled_query",
            "params": {
                "query": query_string,
                "destination_table_name_template": dest_table,
                "write_disposition": write_disposition,
                "partitioning_field": "",
            },
            "schedule": "every day 06:00",  # How can add timezones here?
        },
        bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.TransferConfig(),
    )

    response = client.create_transfer_config(
        parent, transfer_config, authorization_code=authorization_code
    )

    print("Created scheduled query '{}'".format(response.name))
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with the Python Client? Thanks!

Comment: Great question. I can't see anything that's documented. I even inspected the HTTP request when you do it via the console/UI, but I still can't see where the TZ is set in the POST body/params. I also found this, which explains the lack of documentation: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7722. Maybe some of the Googlers can shed some light..

Comment: Looking at the docs (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_manual_run_on_historical_dates), it looks like timezone params are just "display", and the date is converted to UTC before calling the API (check the warning : *The date ranges you provide are in UTC, but your query's schedule is displayed in your local time zone (see Example 2 below to work around this).*). It doesn't answer your question but may help to understand.

Comment: I'll also add that in the [TransferConfig object definition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#scheduleoptions) (used behind the scenes by any client), it is explicitly said that, in the `schedule` field: "*The specified times are in UTC*". I don't believe this is possible to specify a timezone in this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After carefully reviewing the documentation, I concluded that selection the time zone within your Python script is not possible.

Within the [APIs and Reference document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig), you can find out all the possible arguments for you scheduled query in *transfer_config*. The ***schedule*** parameter is described as :

> Data transfer schedule. If the data source does not support a custom
>   schedule, this should be empty. If it is empty, the default value for
>   the data source will be used. The specified times are in UTC. Examples
>   of valid format: 1st,3rd monday of month 15:30, every wed,fri of
>   jan,jun 13:15, and first sunday of quarter 00:00.

Therefore, in the **Console** the time zone selected is used for display purpose only, since the time is converted to **UTC Time** in order to run your scheduled query.

In addition, just as a bonus information, I would like to point that in App Engine you can select the time zone for your scheduled job, using ***cron.yaml***. You can see the ***timezone*** parameter [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#the_schedule_format).

I hope it clarifies your doubt about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is a perfect answer, but you should be passing in the time to execute and the time zone.  Convert that to UTC before you put it in the transfer_config.  (Or don't pass it in and just change it to UTC.

I completely agree that it should support TZs but it doesn't.... next!