# Automatic schedular triggered after bigquery table load

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, airflow

It's about to Trigger automatically schedular after bigquery table get loaded.

In Brief:
I don't want to use weekly schedule Query , that are manual task, I want this to make it automatically trigger the Schedular when table get loaded to the Bigquery table.

Currently I'm using manual weekly schedule query, I want that the query triggers automatically without any Manual things.

I am Just trying to think about logic but not getting koi.

Comment: I don't correctly understood your need. You want trigger an Airflow DAG when data are loaded in a Bigquery table ?

Comment: A Cloud function can be triggered as soon as data is `insert`ed into a table: https://medium.com/@rhimanshu86/event-driven-workflows-in-bigquery-cloud-function-aaa426caf291  You can run Cloud function by a query as well. Please tell your demand in detail.

Comment: Hi @MazlumTosun , i don't think we need DAG for this,  i just want the manual schedular that runs on weekly basis, it's run if data is freshed or not , But I want to make it automatic , it means when my table will be load it will automatically trigger the Schedular, no need weekly schedule for this

Comment: QUESTIONS: Case A: data is loaded by a write or append process to your tables. Case B: you only use insert commands. USE CASE 1: you have a weekly schedule query, which creates table B from the data of table A.  This weekly run of this query shall only run, if the table A has changed. (Goal: Save query resources for execution) USE CASE 2: you want to run a query to create table B, if table A changed or data loaded to it.

Comment: @Samuel , i have a CCN table that is already have data , now we are appending data in that table,  In storage we received files two times in a week, soo for that we have created manual schedular, but i want to replace with automatic trigger, whenever file will come and successful load it will trigger the Schedular automatically without waiting for weekly schedule query trigger,

Comment: I am sorry, but this will be a lot of work step to do for you. First you need to create a cloud function, which triggers as soon as an insert happens to your table. This cloud function should not directly trigger a building query, because sometimes the data is inserted in several steps. Therefore the cloud function has to modify a schedule query (delete and create new one), set to run in several minutes. This can be done in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767487/how-can-i-set-up-scheduled-queries-in-bigquery-with-timezone-support-through-py

Comment: @Samuel thanks, but can you guide me  with more resources?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow doesn't provide an external trigger in the dag, but you can create your dag and trigger it from a cloud function once the table is loaded, this cloud function send a POST http request to Airflow API to trigger a new run with all the params your dag needs to process the data.

To trigger the cloud function, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544813/9560594) which explain how to use [eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs) to listen your bigquery logs from cloud watch, filter them and trigger cloud function run.

To trigger the dag run, you can check the [Airflow API doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run) and the [API security doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html#api) in order to allow cloud function to send requests to the API.